# Аfter assembly, the application does not start from a url different from the root

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

After building the application, if you open the site in the root in production, then everything will be fine. As you navigate the site, everything works great.

This is what source looks like:

[image]

But if I try to go to a url different from the root, for example, `/profile`, then react just breaks:

[image]

Nothing is displayed on the screen and the source is strange.

I created the application using the `create-react-app`.

This is how I send the application from the server:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', "build")));

    app.get('*',
        async(req, res) => {
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
        }
    );
}
```

errors:

[image]

App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

// Pages
import Main from './Pages/Main/Main';
import Auth from './Pages/Auth/Auth';
import Profile from './Pages/Profile/Profile';
import Blog from './Pages/Blog/Blog';
import CreateBlog from './Pages/CreateBlog/CreateBlog';
import PostPage from './Pages/PostPage/PostPage';
import BlogsAndUsers from './Pages/BlogsAndUsers/BlogsAndUsers';

// Components
import Header from './Components/Header/Header';

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="notification-bar"></div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact>
                    <Main />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/auth' exact>
                    <Auth />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/blog/:id' exact>
                    <Blog />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/blogs' exact>
                    <BlogsAndUsers type="blogs" />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/profiles' exact>
                    <BlogsAndUsers type="profiles" />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/create_blog' exact>
                    <CreateBlog />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/profile/:id" exact>
                    <Profile />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/article/:id" exact>
                    <PostPage />
                </Route>
                <Redirect to='/' />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import './fonts/fonts-import.css'

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

this is how it looks:

[image]

sorry for the low resolution.

Comment: show consoel error instead of html generated code

Comment: Please show errors as the complete text of the error, not as an image of the error next to a big block of white pixels.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I did this to demonstrate the behavior of the application

Comment: looks like in production mode your react jsx compilator doesn't work. could you show us the generated js or check this out ?

Comment: @R.LM, Most likely yes, but what can you do about it?

Comment: change your configuration. the default compiler for create react app is babel and bundler is webpack. in production mode there might be some setting not to compile jsx. check webpack config file (you can include it above) or .babelrc file if you have one

Comment: @R.LM, I created the application via `create-react-app`, `webpack.config` is not available to me, on the other hand I can find it in `react-scripts/node_modules`, but will it matter?

Comment: @R.LM, the file has 785 lines

Comment: you are given a few options. first one (the one i'd consider the cleanest but quite painful if it's the first time you manager a webpack/babel transpiling stack) is to eject from create-react-app, second one is to check in create react app issues if this one has already been reported

Comment: @R.LM, unfortunately, I'm zero in webpack, but it's not entirely clear about the second method, how can I check for problems?

Comment: I think you are sending index.hml for all requests.

Comment: @webduvet, what else should I send? In folder `build` only from html only index.html

Comment: @Voprositel I mean for all the get requests from browser you are sending index.html. your browser asks for ***.chunk.js and you return index.html instead of js bundle...

Comment: try removing line with app.get...

Comment: @webduvet, now the server returns a bad request

Comment: debug the server. do you see that `<` unexpected token? that is your content of index.html. if browser asks for resurce you need to fetch the resource.